# How to download xlsx file from URL and save in data frame via python

Tags: python, pandas, download

I would like the following code to download the xlsx files from the URL and save in drive.

I receive this error:

> AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'content'

Below is the code:

```
import requests
import xlrd
import pandas as pd

filed = 'https://www.icicipruamc.com/downloads/others/monthly-portfolio-disclosures/monthly-portfolio-disclosure-november19/Arbitrage.xlsx'

resp = requests.get(filed)

workbook = xlrd.open_workbook(file_contents = filed.content)
worksheet = workbook.sheet_by_index(0)
first_row = worksheet.row(0)

df = pd.DataFrame(first_row)
```

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow, I'd like to ask you to read your source code again, you'll find that you switched up some variables.

Comment: thanks @Vulpex. I changed the file_contents = rest.content and now I am getting belo error: XLRDError: Unsupported format, or corrupt file: Expected BOF record; found b' <!DOCTY'

Comment: Also not sure if the URL syntax is correct. if one goes to the website below:
https://www.icicipruamc.com/downloads/others/monthly-portfolio-disclosures

I want to download " Monthly disclosures of November 2019"

so not sure if the syntax in the above code is correct

Answer (score 4):

pandas already has a function thas converts excel direclty into pandas dataframe (using xlrd):

```py
import pandas as pd

MY_EXCEL_URL="www.yes.com/xl.xlsx"
xl_df = pd.read_excel(MY_EXCEL_URL,
                       sheet_name='my_sheet',
                       skiprows=range(5),
                       skipfooter=0)
```

then yo can handle /save file using `pd.DataFrame.to_excel`

Comment: Saving file is not the concern. as mentioned above, the error is coming while using my code. I am not sure if the url syntax is correct. as no content appeared.

Answer (score 0):

This function works, tested individual components. The ICICI website you have seems to give me a 404. So make sure the website works and has an excel sheet before trying this out.

```py
import requests
import pandas as pd

def excel_to_pandas(URL, local_path):
    resp = requests.get(URL)
    with open(local_path, 'wb') as output:
        output.write(resp.content)
    df = pd.read_excel(local_path)
    return df


print(excel_to_pandas("www.websiteforxls.com", '~/Desktop/my_downloaded.xls'))
```

As a footnote, this was super simple. And I'm disappointed you couldn't do this on your own. I might not have been able to do this 5 years ago, and that's why I decided to help.

If you want to code. Learn the basics, literally the basics: Class, Functions, Variables, Types, OOP principals. And that's all you need to start. Then you need to learn how to search, and make different components to work together the way you require them too. And with SO, if you show some effort, we are happy to help. We are a community, not a place to solve your homework. Try harder next time.

Comment: I used your suggestion, but got this error:

FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '<path/to/file/to/save>.xlrd'

Comment: That's because you need to put your own path in there. For example, if you want it on your desktop: open('~/Desktop/temporary_file.xlsx', 'wb').write(myfile.content) Make sure the formati s correct. Could be `xlsx` or `xls` or `xlrd` - dunno that bit.

Comment: my bad.... I have amended the code to "open('test.xlrd', 'wb').write(resp.content)
" and it is saving the file, but xlrd format is not opening. how can I save the result in a data frame now. please help

Comment: `df = excel_file.parse(myfile)`  read [this](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/loading-excel-spreadsheet-as-pandas-dataframe/)

Comment: were you able to fetch the data from the URL and save the same in data frame?

Comment: I should get a discount, as a fresher in python coding.. just 20 days old.

Comment: If you show some effort, the entire SO community will try to help you. If you use SO as a means to solve your homework, every coder here has better things to do.

Comment: Anyways thanks a lot for your help .... I assume I need to spend more time on internet to get right syntax for my URL and then see the data in a data frame.

Comment: Alright, today i'm going to solve this for you. You want to download an excel worksheet from the URL you've given, and then convert that to a pandas dataframe. Let me know if correct, I'll attempt this in a while.

Comment: let me check and get back to you